# How can I give the elements of the following set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image]

Well, in this case i is equal to true and h for false.

$ \underline{4} = \{ 1,2,3,4\}$
The statements are the following:

$ \{a \in \underline{4}:(\exists x \in \underline{4})(Q(a,x) \land Q(x,x)$

Well I think that I have to check the pairs:$(1,x) \land (x,x)$,$(2,x) \land (x,x)$,$(3,x) \land (x,x)$,$(4,x) \land (x,x)$ and these $(x,x)$pairs are in the diagonal, and in the diagonal these are always i so true. But how can I give the elements of the set? I still can see what would be the difference if I would use $\forall$ instead of $\exists$.

The other statement is:

$ \{a \in \underline{4}:(\forall x \in \underline{4})(\exists y \in \underline{4})(Q(a,x) \implies Q(x,y) \land Q(y,a)))\}$

I'm a little bit perplexed again

Comment: Not very clear... but yes. $Q(x,x)$ always holds; thus $Q(a,x) ∧ Q(x,x)$ amounts to $Q(a,x)$. And thus, $(∃x)Q(a,x)$ holds for every $a \in \underline 4$, exactly because $Q(a,a)$ holds.

Comment: The case with $\forall$ is different because $\forall x Q(a,x)$ does not hold for e.g. $a=1$ because $Q(1,4)$ has $h$, i.e. FALSE.

Comment: For the other one, you have to calculate it one by one. $a=1$ then you have to consider $\forall x$, i.e. the four cases with $x=1,2,3,4$ in turn. $4$ is ok, because $Q(1,4)$ is FALSE, and thus the conditional is TRUE. Then we have to consider $x=1$ and we have $Q(1,1) \to (Q(1,y) \land Q(y,1))$ : Ok for $y=1$ and then $x=2$ and we have $Q(1,2) \to (Q(2,y) \land Q(y,1))$ and we have to check if we can find a suitable $y$, and the same for $x=3$.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).  \begin{array}{r|rr} Q & 1 & 2 \\\hline 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 &4 \end{array}

Comment: I know that my notation isn't perfect, but can I maybe rewrite the first statement as $(1,x) \land Q(x,x) = (1,1) \land (1,1)$

$(2,x) \land Q(x,x) = (2,2) \land (2,2)$

$(3,x) \land Q(x,x) = (3,3) \land (3,3)$

$(4,x) \land Q(x,x) = (4,4) \land (4,4)$  So the elements are:$(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)$